# Creating a Pytorch DataLoader from 8 Data Frames?

Tags: python, pytorch

My training data is in 8 Data Frames, 1 data frame for each feature. Each data frame has 11 rows, or time steps, and 4,232,460 columns.

I'm trying to create a Pytorch Dataset class and Data Loader, where the each sample would 1 column from each data frame. For example, the first sample would be the first column of each data frame, second sample would be the second column of each data frame, etc. Below is what I've tried.

```
class CustomDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, data_frames_list, target_list):
        self.data_frames_list = data_frames_list
        self.target_list = target_list
        self.num_samples = len(data_frames_list[0]) 

    def __len__(self):
        return self.num_samples

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        # Get the idx-th sample from each data frame
        samples = [df.iloc[:, idx].values for df in self.data_frames_list]

        # Convert the list of samples to a PyTorch tensor
        samples = torch.FloatTensor(samples)
        target = torch.FloatTensor([self.target_list[idx]])

        return samples, target
```

This class does seem to work, it returns a sample of shape (8,11) and the target. However, when I try to create the data loader, it only let's me do a batch size of 8(which is the # of data frames I have). Additionally, it only creates 1 batch of 8 samples even though I have 4,232,460 samples

```
batch_size = 8
train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True, drop_last=True)

num_batches = len(train_loader)
print(f'Number of batches in train_loader: {num_batches}')

>>> Number of batches in train_loader: 1
```

It also only allows me to do a batch size of 8 because there are 8 data frames, but I should be able to do larger batches. Ideally, each batch should randomly pick an index from the range of samples, and select that column index from each data frame to create a batch. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is how you have specified the `__len__` attribute of your dataset.

Your `__len__` returns `self.num_samples`, which is defined as `self.num_samples = len(data_frames_list[0])`. The `len` of a dataframe returns the number of rows. Your dataframes have 11 rows, so `__len__` returns 11.

With `__len__=11` and `batch_size=8`, the `DataLoader` will give you one full batch of size 8 and one ragged batch of size 3. Since you pass `drop_last=True` to the `DataLoader`, the ragged batch is dropped. This is why the `DataLoader` shows only one batch.

To avoid confusion, I would recommend combining all the dataframes into a single tensor of size `(4,232,460, 8, 11)` as a preprocessing step prior to creating the dataset.